# How do I change class name of elements provided array of ids of those elements?

Tags: javascript

I want to request an ajax and change class-names of the ids that is received through the response. all of the ids are joint with a separator ','.

sample response string:

> "s12,s23,s34,s43,s44"

I've tried to access elements inside a loop and used 'className' property to set the new class. But it doesn't work for some reason.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "actions/updateBookedSeats.php",
  method: "GET",
  data: {
    movie_id: mov,
    date: showDate,
    time: showt,
    hall: hall
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var seats = data.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(seats[i]).className = "se_bkd";
    }
  }
});
```

The code should be able to change class names of the elements (Which I know when the change the color ). But they just don't.

Comment: **It's just** (effectively) **a typo.** (Voting to close as such.) `0` should be `i` in `document.getElementById(seats[0]).className="se_bkd"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He's corrected the typo and claims it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Is your `seats` an array of string ids?

Comment: BTW, it's generally a bad idea to use `GET` for an update operation.

Comment: isnt it data.split*

Comment: @Kevin.a - Yup, another typo-style error, and another problem that would show up in the web console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "actions/updateBookedSeats.php",
  method: "GET",
  data: {
    movie_id: mov,
    date: showDate,
    time: showDate,
    hall: hall
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var seats = data.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(seats[i]).className = "se_bkd";
    }
  }
});
```

You're not incrementing the value, which is why i assume you made the for loop for. You are also using the split method wrong. You cant use it on it's own , since it's part of the String object.

Comment: Don't bother posting an answer to a simple typo like this. Just vote to close.

Comment: My bad @Barmar just wanted to help

Comment: My bad. Actually I completely modified this code several times and even when I put `i` in there, it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheUnicodist could you give the new code i posted a try. If it doesnt work consider posting the console errors in your question